# How can I get a period of time before date now in php?

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to get a period of time with a date such as today is `"2011-11-24"` and I want to get 7 days before today:

The values would be :

```
"2011-11-23", "2011-11-22", "2011-11-21", "2011-11-20", 
"2011-11-19", "2011-11-18", "2011-11-17"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the new date/time classes you can do the following:

```
$p = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('now'), 
    DateInterval::createFromDateString('-1 day'), 
    7, 
    DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE
);
foreach ($p as $t) {
    echo $t->format('Y-m-d') . '<br />';
}
```

See [`DatePeriod`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php), [`DateTime`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).

Comment: thanks, And I want to know does the way of liquorvicar can run faster?

Comment: The way liquorvicar shows is faster - for sure. The solution above is more flexible, supports different timezones, works outside the range of Unix timestamps and may handle DST changes more correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm reading you right you want each of the previous seven days. Something like this would work:

```
$today = time();
for( $daysAgo = 1; $daysAgo <= 7; $daysAgo++ ) {
    echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( "-$daysAgo days", $today ) ) . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$timestamp = strtotime('YYYY-MM-DD - 1 week');
```

http://php.net/strtotime

Answer (score 0):

```
$timestamp = time() - (7*60*60*24);

echo date('Y-m-d',$timestamp);
```

Comment: sorry, that only can get one value,I want get some value of date

Comment: Then you simply use mktime or another function to create a timestamp from your date. But I'd go for liquorvicar version.